# How to fill all columns before moving to next row in for loop in R?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have created a for nested loop to create a matrix. I want two rows to be filled in this matrix with 17 columns. I want to fill my first entire row with all 17 columns before moving to the next row. Any suggestions?

````
```{r}
AH2<-matrix(NA,nrow=2,ncol=n_taxa)

for(i in 1:nrow(AH2)){
 for (j in 1:ncol(AH2)){

  AH2[j]<-quantile(A_resample[,taxa[j]], 
probs = c(0.975),na.rm=TRUE)
  AH2[j]<-quantile(FSE_resample[,taxa[j]], 
probs = c(0.975),na.rm=TRUE)
  }
 }
 AH2
```
````

It produces results like this:

```
          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]    [,5]      [,6]      [,7]        

[1,] 0.03972008 0.04302462 0.09159327 0.04167977 0.05826623 0.05627512 
0.008241821
[2,] 0.15993208 0.26306033 0.06768178 0.03120404 0.00000000 0.05036500 
0.011013251
           [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17]
[1,] 0.01263579    0    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
[2,] 0.00000000   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! sample input and output pls?